# Are ntdll's exported functions the same whatever the version?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64, wow64, ntdll

I am currently planning on hooking some ntdll's exported functions to monitor them.
I would like this idea to work on every sub-version of Windows 10 and 11.

On every computers I checked, the exported functions that got my interest were defined as:

```
mov eax, functionID
mov edx, ptr_to_ntdll_wow64Transition
call edx
ret {} ; number of bytes to pop out
; followed by a NOP after the ret
```

The functions being defined that way all have the same length : 18 bytes (excluding the NOP)
That means I could hook at the beginning, by replacing `mov eax, functionID` by a jmp, do my stuff and then apply the 18 copied bytes.
But for this, I need ntdll's exported functions to be stable enough across Windows version, does anyone have experience with it?

Thank you by advance

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/Detours

Comment: There is **no** guarantee that the [implementation details of WOW64](https://wbenny.github.io/2018/11/04/wow64-internals.html#leaving-32-bit-mode) remain stable AFAIK. However, you can check if the function is made of the instructions pattern you posted and back off if not. After all, it's just four instructions.